# How to Change the value of SVG path 'd' attribute inside a loop?

Tags: php, svg

I have a svg output which i need to change the postion of d attribute alone of Moving property.

Example output:

```
[path] => SimpleXMLElement Object
           (
               [@attributes] => Array
                   (
                       [class] => fil0
                       [d] => M114 160c0,0 0,0 0,0l0 0 1 0c0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,0 0,
                   0 1,0 1,0 1,0 1,0 2,-1 0,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,
                   0 0,0 0,0 1,0l0 0c0,-1 -1,-1 -1,-2 -1,0 -2,0 -3,0 0,-1 -1,-1 -2,-2 0,
                   0 -1,-1 -1,-2 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 1,0 1,0 1,-1 0,0 0,-1 1,-2 0,-1 1,-2 2,-4 1,
                   -2 2,-3 4,-5 1,-2 2,-3 3,-5 1,-1 2,-3 3,-4 1,-1 1,-1 2,-1l0 0c0,0 1,0 1,
                   0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,0 0,-1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 0,0 0,0 0,
                   0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,-1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,0 1,
                   -1 2,-1 2,-1 1,-1 2,-1 2,-2 1,0 1,0 1,-1 0,0 0,0 -1,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,
                   -1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,-1 0,0 1,-1 1,-1 1,-1 2,-1 2,-2 1,-1 1,-1 1,-2 0,-1 0,
                   -1 0,-1 0,-1 0,-1 0,-2 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 1,0 1,-1 1,-1l0 -1 0 -1 0 0c0,-1 0,-1 1,-1 0,
                   -1 0,-1 0,-2 0,0 0,0 0,-1 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,
                   0 1,-1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 0,-1l0 0 0 0c0,0 0,0 -1,1 0,0 0,0 -1,0l0 0c-1,0 -1,0 -1,
                   0 0,0 0,0 0,0l0 0 0 0 1 -1c0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,
                   -1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 0,-1l3 -5c0,-1 0,-3 0,-4 0,
                   -2 1,-3 1,-4l1 0c0,0 0,0 0,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 1,0 2,-1 2,-2 1,-1 1,-2 2,-3 0,-1 0,-2 0,-3 0,-2 1,
                   -2 1,-3 0,0 0,0 0,-1 1,0 1,0 1,0 1,-1 1,-2 1,-3 0,-1 0,-2 0,-3 0,-2 0,-3 0,-4 0,-1 -1,-2 -1,
                   -3 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 0,0 -1,0 -1,0l0 -1 0 -1 0 -1 0 0c0,-1 0,-2 0,-2 0,-1 0,-1 0,-2 0,0 0,-1 0,
                   -2 0,-1 0,-1 0,-2 0,-1 0,-2 -1,-2 0,-1 0,-2 -1,-2 0,-1 -1,-1 -1,-2 -1,0 -2,-1 -2,-1l0 -1 0 -1c0,
                   0 0,0 0,-1 -1,0 -1,0 -1,-1 0,0 0,0 -1,-1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,1 -2,2 -3,2 -1,
                   1 -2,1 -3,2 -2,2 -5,4 -7,5 -2,2 -4,4 -7,5 0,0 0,0 0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 0,
                   0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 -2,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 -1,0 -1,0 -2,0 0,
                   0 0,0 -1,0 -2,1 -4,1 -5,2 -2,0 -4,1 -6,2 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,0 0,0 -1,0 0,0 0,1 0,1 -1,0 -1,
                   0 -2,0 -1,0 -1,0 -2,0 0,0 -1,1 -1,1 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,
                   0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 -2,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0l0 0c-1,0 -1,0 -2,0 0,0 0,-1 -1,-1 0,0 0,-1 -1,-1 0,-1 0,-1 0,
                   -1l-4 -4c-1,-1 -3,-2 -4,-2 -1,-1 -3,-2 -4,-3 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,-1 -1,-1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,
                   0 -1,-1 -2,-1 -3,-1 -1,0 -2,-1 -3,-1 -1,0 -2,0 -3,0 -1,0 -2,0 -3,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,
                   0 -1,-1 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0l0 0c0,0 -1,1 -1,1 0,0 0,0 -1,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,0 -1,
                   1 -1,1 0,0 0,0 -1,0 0,0 -1,1 -1,1 -1,0 -1,0 -1,0 -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 0,1 0,1 0,2 0,0 0,0 0,1 0,0 0,0 1,0 0,
                   1 0,1 0,1 0,0 0,1 -1,1 -1,0 -1,1 -2,1 -1,1 -1,1 -2,1 -1,1 -1,1 -1,2 1,0 2,0 3,0 2,0 3,0 4,0 0,0 1,0 2,
                   1 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,0 1,0 2,1 0,0 1,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,1 1,2 0,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,2 0,0 0,0 0,1 0,0 0,
                   0 0,1 0,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,2 0,2 0,4 0,5 0,2 0,4 0,5l0 1 0 1 0 0c0,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,2 0,2 0,1 0,2 0,3 1,
                   0 1,1 1,1 0,1 1,2 1,3 1,1 1,2 2,2 0,1 0,2 1,3 0,1 1,2 1,3 0,0 0,0 1,0 0,0 0,1 0,1 0,0 1,0 1,0 0,1 0,1 0,
                   1 1,1 2,2 3,3 1,1 1,2 2,3 1,1 2,1 3,2 1,1 2,2 3,3 1,0 1,0 1,1 0,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,1 1,0 1,
                   0 1,0 1,1 1,1 1,1 0,-1 0,-1 0,-1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 -1,0 0,0 0,0 0,-1 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,0 1,0 2,1 1,1 2,2 3,
                   3 1,1 2,2 3,3 1,1 2,1 2,2 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,0 2,1 2,1 1,1 2,1 3,1 0,1 1,1 1,1 0,0 0,1 1,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,0 1,
                   0 0,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1l0 0c0,0 0,1 0,1 0,0 0,0 -1,1 0,0 0,0 0,1 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,1 -1,1 -1,2 0,
                   1 -1,2 -1,3 -1,1 -1,2 -2,3 0,0 0,1 0,1 -1,1 -2,2 -2,3 -1,1 -1,2 -2,2 0,1 -1,1 -2,2 -1,0 -2,0 -3,0 0,0 -1,0 -2,
                   0 0,0 -1,0 -2,0 -1,1 -1,1 -2,1 -1,0 -1,0 -2,0 -1,0 -2,0 -3,1 -1,0 -2,1 -2,2l0 0c4,0 7,0 11,-1 5,0 9,2 12,
                   -3l2 -2c0,-2 0,-3 1,-4 0,-1 1,-2 2,-4 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,-1 0,-1 0,-1 0,-1 1,-3 2,-4 0,-1 1,-2 1,-4 0,0 1,0 1,
                   0 0,0 0,0 0,0l0 0c1,0 2,0 3,0 0,1 1,1 2,1l0 0c0,0 1,0 1,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,-1 1,-1 1,-1 0,0 0,0 1,0 0,0 1,0 1,1 0,
                   1 0,1 0,2 0,0 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 0,1 -1,1 -1,2 0,0 -1,1 -1,1 0,1 -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 -1,1 -1,1l-3 4c0,1 -1,1 -1,1 0,
                   0 -1,0 -1,1l-6 6 0 0c0,0 0,0 1,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 0,0 1,0 1,1 1,0 2,0 2,0 1,0 1,0 2,0 1,0 1,0 1,0l2 0 1 0z
                       [fill] => #000000
                   )

           )
```

I need to change the M114 to 282 and 160 to 432. Is this possible to achieve in php?

Comment: you could simply find and replace... So the answer to your question is Yes it is possible.

Comment: These values are dynamic

Comment: That's just where the path starts so add a translate transform to the path and use that to put it wherever you want.